# setgid() fails - operation not permitted

Tags: c, linux, permissions, setuid

I created a setuid program in C. The executable looks like this:

```
-r-s-r-s--- 1 root users 13073 Jun 15 21:56 server
```

I execute the program as `userA/users` and try to set the uid/gid to `userB/otherUsers`. `setgid()` fails with Operation not permitted. `userA` is not part of `otherUsers` How can I change the effective gid?

---

**[EDIT]** Here is a small summary of what I did. My C program, executed as userA, sets uid and gid to userB and creates a file. Not as expected, the file belongs to the group root, because `setgid()` fails.

```
[userA@node uid]$ id
uid=11945(userA) gid=544(users) groups=544(users)
[userA@node uid]$ id userB
uid=11946(userB) gid=10792(otherUsers) groups=10792(otherUsers)
[userA@node uid]$ cat uid.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  setuid(11946);
  setgid(10792);

FILE *f = fopen("userB_file", "w");
fclose(f);

return 0;
}
[userA@node uid]$ ls -l uid
-r-sr-sr-x 1 root root 7130 Jun 17 14:16 uid
[userA@node uid]$ ./uid 
[userA@node uid]$ ls -l userB_file 
-rw-r--r-- 1 userB root 0 Jun 17 14:19 userB_file
```

Comment: Are you sure `setgid()` is running with the permissions of a user in the `users` group? That would cause it to fail with "Operation not permitted" because the read and exec/setuid privs don't extend to world/other.

Comment: I don't get that. Do I have to run my program as root? I thought setting the owner to root would be enough to change uid/gid. I won't be able to run the program as root.

Comment: Unix permissions are owner / group / {world,other}. You have read and exec+setuid for owner (root) and group (users). You don't have your code posted, but if whatever is calling setgid() isn't either root or in the group users, that would give the error you're reporting.

Comment: I'm just calling setuid() and setgid() with the id's for userB/otherUsers. The program itself is executed by userA. Should I add some example code?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I suspect you're calling `setuid` before `setgid`. As soon as you call `setuid` to change the uid to something other than root, you've forfeited your permission to change the gid to an arbitrary value. You must call `setgid` first, then `setuid`.

Comment: This is as obvious as simple! Damn, you're so right. I changed the order and of course, it works! Thanks.

btw: I added my original C program in the question.

Comment: It is actually not so obvious. It is not reported in the man page of setgid and neither in the man page of setuid.

Comment: @Bemipefe: It should be obvious as a consequence of the permission model that you can't change your group id to anything you want when you're a normal unprivileged user.

Comment: @R.. I was referring to the fact that the setgid function must be called before the setuid function. This rule applies also to processes  wich run as root user.

Comment: @Bemipefe: That "rule" is just a consequence of the fact that only root can change gid to arbitrary groups. After calling `setuid` you're no longer root.